# Slashing first row from HTTP response in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently working on ingesting HTTP endpoint using InvokeHTTP processor into HDFS. My HTTP endpoint is: [http://www.cbioportal.org/webservice.do?cmd=getMutationData&case_set_id=gbm_tcga_all&genetic_profile_id=gbm_tcga_mutations&gene_list=TP53+PIK3CA](http://www.cbioportal.org/webservice.do?cmd=getMutationData&case_set_id=gbm_tcga_all&genetic_profile_id=gbm_tcga_mutations&gene_list=TP53%20PIK3CA).

As you may notice, I would like to slash the first row and then push into HDFS. 
I looked into properties of the InvokeHTTP but there is no feature such as to remove header row etc. 
I would like to know what could be the most effective way to deal in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sequence of `SplitText` and `MergeContent`

but most effective will be script, IHMO.

`ExecuteScript(groovy)`

```
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return
ff = session.write(ff, {rawIn, rawOut->
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
        rawIn.eachLine("UTF-8"){line,index->
            if(index>1)writer.append(line).append('\n')
        }
    }
} as StreamCallback)
session.transfer(ff, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to drop the first line of any FlowFile content is to run it through the linux command 'sed 1d' using an ExecuteStreamCommand processsor.
[image: ExecuteStreamCommand for sed 1d in NiFi-1.2.0]